# Annotation loading of Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, annotations

I have defined an entity

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
/**
 * UmMemberSectionInfo
 *
 * @Table(name="um_member_section_info")
 * @Annotations\CharDependent(reflect="TbContentcharset")
 * @Entity
 */
class UmMemberSectionInfo extends \DoctrineHelper
{
//some code
}
```

And an annotation

```
namespace Annotations;
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation;
/**
 * @Annotation
 * @Target("CLASS")
 */
final class CharDependent extends Annotation{
    public $reflect;
}
```

And read it as

```
$reader = new AnnotationReader();        
$reflectionObj = new \ReflectionObject(new $entity);
$annot = $reader->getClassAnnotation($reflectionObj, '\\Annotations\\CharDependent');
var_dump($annot->reflect);
if ($annot instanceof \Annotations\CharDependent) {}
```

However, it just pom an error says, `The annotation "@Table" in class UmMemberSectionInfo was never imported.` which will not be shown when I let the  `CharDependent` annotation off and use it as original. What is the problem? Why it's fine when I use the original?

Answer (score 1):

You must use full annotation name with namespace:

```
@Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table
```

but you imported `use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`, so you can use that alias:

```
@ORM\Table
```

If you want to use short `@Table`, you must import `Table` class:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Table;
```

You must do the same for `@Entity`.

Comment: So, the build in AnnotationReader will not import it by default?